# AngularJS : Why can't $interpolate render ng-style?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile, angularjs-interpolate

I have created a drop down input directive, where the user can pass in a template string to set what the list will actually render.
In my example I am passing in `<div style="background-color: darkgrey" ng-style="{\'color\':  isActive?\'red\':\'blue\'}">{{index}}</div>` so it will render the items index number and then color it based on isActive. The index is show properly, and the background color is right but ng-style is being ignored. 
I create the template in a setTimeout because I have to wait for ng-repeat to render the `<li>`.

```
    setTimeout(function() {
         var spanList = elm.find('li');
         for (var index = 0; index < scope.list.length; index++) {
             var listElm = angular.element(spanList[index]);
             var listData = scope.list[index]
             listElm.html($interpolate(scope.listTemplate)(listData));
         }
     }, 0);
```

I am iterating through the `<li>` elements and setting the template for each one. I am using $interpolate instead of $compile because using $compile would result in [[Object HTMLDivElement]] and I couldn't figure out why. From what I can tell $compile uses $interpolate anyways, and it works except that ng-style, ng-show, and ng-hide don't work. Why would angular's directives not work with $interpolate?

Here is the working example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aFgW8g?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$interpolate` returns a function which returns a string. It is used to resolve `{{bindings}}`.

`$compile` returns a function which returns an html-element. It is used to compile raw (html) strings into html-elements and resolve angular-code inside of this string. `$compile` uses `$interpolate` to resolve any bindings inside this string.

In your case you probably want to use `$compile` and `.replaceWith()`.

Comment: Makes sense then the issue remains that $compile is giving me [[Object HTMLDivElement]] instead of the element.

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer, you should look into `replaceWith` in your case (instead of previous append).

Answer (score 0):

`$interpolate` is only for interpreting markup (example, "{{firstName}} {{lastName}}"):

### AngularJS Documentation

`$interpolate` is a service used by `$compile`:

> Compiles a string with markup into an interpolation function.

`ngStyle`, `ngShow`, etc do not rely on interpolation. Instead they rely on the `$parse` service to evaluate the AngularJS expression, and determine how to render the behavior.

`$compile` is appropriate in your scenario because it compiles the template HTML fragment by activating any directives within it, which indirectly calls `$parse` to evaluate expressions. Remember to append the template to the DOM before you `$compile` because directives may rely on parent directives higher up the DOM.  I recommend the following pattern:

```
 var e = angular.element(someTemplate); 
 element.append(e);
 $compile(e)($scope);
```